# Mosfet PWM vs Pot

Tags: led, mosfet, pwm

I have a dumb question concerning MOSFETs. When considering voltage to the Gate, is there any benefit to using a PWM signal vs a variable voltage from a pot beside power savings? If I am trying to achieve a dimming effect, for example, to a few LEDs, then what is the big deal using a pot if it is resistive enough to limit the current to something insignificant? Thanks.

Comment: The wording in most of your question indicates you want to know the difference between applying PWM to a MOSFET gate versus using a potentiometer to apply a continuously variable voltage to a MOSFET gate. But the last sentence indicates that you want to compare the difference between PWMing a MOSFET to reduce current versus just using a potentiometer to reduce current.

Comment: As well as power savings, you need to consider where that power goes. Controlling conduction in the MOSFET with a pot, the MOSFET gets hot, so you have to add the cost and room for a big heatsink.

Comment: you can scale pwm from 0 to 1 pretty well, but it's hard to scale gate voltage from just below turn-on to full "saturation", and that voltage requirement can change with load and temp. In short, use PWM.

Comment: It depends on the "few LEDs", but there's nothing wrong with keeping it simple and using discrete components (passives no doubt) instead of an MCU gets you nerd cred. As long as your pot isn't overheating and your batteries are dying far too soon, that's a perfectly acceptable way to dim some signal LEDs.

Comment: using a resistor to dim LEDs saves power compared to using PWM

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes, I know the difference but was just wondering if there are any other benefits or detriments that one method provides over the other since there is so much mud thrown on the internet over using one technique vs another. Thanks.

Comment: @dandavis Ah ok, so PWM gives you finer control over how much you open the gate of the MOSFET. I will have to hit the bench and test both out, but I was planning on utilizing the transistor for higher current loads possibly in the amp range. Thanks.